# Docker Differentiate multiple containers log folder at same host machine

Tags: docker

I am able to run a docker image and can connect log file in a container into a host machine volume .

I wonder how I can differentiate two containers of same running images at same host?
May be container ids can be used but I donot know how I can pass container id into log4j.xml file as a parameter?

Comment: Could you use one host volume per container? Or another method as in https://www.loggly.com/blog/top-5-docker-logging-methods-to-fit-your-container-deployment-strategy/?

Comment: for this case I have to reach container name inside container, I mean I can pass the values of "cat /etc/hostname" as a JVM parameter to be used at log4j.xml.  Is there any other simple solution